# How to compute cheaply this matrix product in MATLAB

Tags: matrices, algorithms, matlab

is there a way to compute this matrix product more efficently then the standard MATLAB multiplication?

$$D_1A^TD_2A$$
where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are $n\times n$ diagonal matrices.

I tried this script but maybe it is not so cheap.

`function B=prodiag(d1,d2,A)
N=size(A,1);
for(i=1:N)
    c_ij=zeros(1,N);
    for(j=1:N)
        c_ij=c_ij+d2(j)*A(j,i)*A(j,:);
    end
    B(i,:)=d1(i)*c_ij;
end
end`

Comment: For loops are slow in Matlab, so you should avoid for loops. What if you just store $D_1$ and $D_2$ as sparse matrices? That might speed it up a lot. How large are these matrices? How slow is it now and how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: I am working with $n =10^4$. Now it takes about 3 minutes for computing that product in the standard way. I would like to improve it as much as possible. I will try to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Storing $D_1$ and $D_2$ as sparse matrices it takes about 1 minute. But for my purpose is too slow yet.

Comment: Is $A$ sparse? How long does it take to compute $A^T A$? It's hard to beat Matlab's built in matrix operations.

Comment: A is full and does not have any particular structure. Computation of $A^TA$ takes 35 seconds.

Comment: I can do the Matlab command `A'* A` when $A$ is a full $10,000 \times 10,000$ matrix in about 4 seconds on my (quite powerful) desktop PC. I doubt it's possible to do much better than Matlab's built in operations. If you have a GPU with a lot of RAM, you could try putting these matrices on the GPU using Matlab's gpuarray command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store d1 as a column vector and d2 as a row vector, you could do

d1(:,ones(n,1)).*A'.*d2(ones(1,n),:)*A;